# Oracle Apex 5.1 Passing HTML string into Region

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm passing a value which is a HTML unordered string from an interactive report to a new page, and wanting to add it to a static content region on another page (with HTML attribute set to 'yes').

However, it displays literally as shown in the image.

If I hard-code `Hello <strong> World</strong>` into the region it displays as expected.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **Escape special characters** attribute in your report to Yes.

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2017/01/escape-special-characters-apex-demo.html

And perhaps your popup needs this, depending on how you implemented it.

```
&P1_TEXT!HTML.
```

http://roelhartman.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/apex-5-new-substitution-syntax-features.html

Answer (score 0):

Extended substitution string can be used to escape special characters. Check out Oracle docs --> [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/understanding-substitution-strings.htm#GUID-CA3ABA44-D03D-4396-A527-B160F1FFE933) for more information. Also, take security into account before implementing as output escaping is an important security technique to avoid Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.